# Задача «Разложение на чётнопростые»

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика, олимпиада, простые-числа

Всем здравствуйте! Никак не получается решить одну задачу.

**Условие задачи:**
В этой задаче рассматриваются только *чётные* целые числа. Чётное натуральное число  будем называть *чётнопростым* числом, если его нельзя представить в виде *произведения двух чётных* чисел. Например, числа `2` и `6` — чётнопростые. Очевидно, что каждое число либо является чётнопростым, либо *разлагается* в *произведение чётнопростых*. Но такое разложение на чётнопростые *не всегда единственно*.

**Входные данные:**
Дано чётное натуральное  `≤ 109`.

**Выходные данные:**
Если число  — чётнопростое, выведите слово `prime`. Если это число единственным образом разлагается в произведение двух и более чётнопростых, то выведите слово `single`, а в следующей строке выведите разложение этого числа на чётнопростые множители. Если число допускает несколько различных разложений на чётнопростые, то выведите слово `many`, а в следующих двух строках выведите два каких-нибудь различных разложения числа на чётнопростые множители. Сложность алгоритма должна быть `О(√n)`.

**Мой код:**

```
def even_prime_check(n): # проверка числа на чётно-простоту
    if n%4 == 0:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def even_prime_factorization(n): # функция для не чётно-простого числа
    a = []
    b = []
    a.append(n//2)
    a.append(2)
    check1 = a[0]
    check2 = a[1]

    for d in range(6,10**6,4):
        if n%d == 0 and even_prime_check(n//d) and n//d != check2 and d != check1:
            b.append(n//d)
            b.append(d)
            break

    return a,b

n = int(input())
a,b = even_prime_factorization(n)

if even_prime_check(n):
    print('prime')

elif len(a) == 2 and len(b) == 0:
    print('single')
    print(' '.join(map(str, a)))

elif len(a) == 2 and len(b) == 2:
    print('many')
    print(' '.join(map(str, a)))
    print(' '.join(map(str, b)))
```

Я тестирую эту программу, вроде всё верно. Но моё решение засчитывается как неверное. Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку и исправить код.

Comment: Проверка на четнопростоту - не делится на 4. Всё.

Comment: @Harry, я изменил функцию проверки на чётнопростоту, но программа до сих пор не проходит проверку (19/28 тестов пройдено). Ещё непонятная ситуация, если ввести цифру `8`: программа ничего не выводит. По сути, `8` — и не чётнопростое, и нет чётнопростых делителей (`4` — не чётнопростое). Непонятно, как с этим справится.

Comment: Понимаете, я знаю, как решить, но не знаю, как это написать на Питоне :( Хотите, дам решение на С++?

Comment: @Daniil Savinov   `8 = 2 * 2 * 2`  двух **и более**

Comment: @Harry, Боюсь, не смогу перевести… Совсем его не знаю. Может, Вы можете написать решение на C++, описывая при помощи комментария каждую строчку? Тогда мне будет проще понять, что Вы делаете. Или можете просто текстом написать последовательность Ваших действий. Сделайте, как Вам удобно. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ideone.com/jlfdZu

```
def solve(n):
  d = 0
  while not (n&1):
    d += 1
    n //= 2

  a = [2]*d
  a[-1] *= n

  if d == 1:
    print("prime")
    return

  for x in range(3, int(n**.5)+1, 2):
    if not (n%x):
      b = a[:]
      b[-1] //= x
      b[-2] *= x
      print("many")
      print(" ".join(map(str, a)))
      print(" ".join(map(str, b)))
      return

  print("single")
  print(" ".join(map(str, a)))

from sys import stdin

for line in stdin:
  print("=== " + line.strip() + " ===")
  solve(int(line))
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое! Решение прошло проверку. Только Ваше решение мне немного непонятно. Мне хотелось бы в нём разобраться. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что Вы делаете на строках №3-8, №14-18 и №27-31?

Comment: 27-31 - это чтение ввода пока он не закончится и обработка числа в каждой строке.

Answer (score 4):

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    if (n%4)                // Если не делится на 4 - выводим, что простое
    {
        cout << "prime\n";
        return 0;
    }
    int two = 0;            // Считаем степень 2 в разложении
    while(n%2 == 0)         // пока делится на 2 - 
    {
        two++;              // увеличиваем показатель
        n /= 2;             // само число делим на 2
    }
    vector<int> ps;         // Здесь массив нечетных простых делителей

    for(int d = 3; n > 1 && d*d <= n; d+=2)   // Для всех нечетных делителей от 3
    {                         // и до корня из n, с шагом 2
        while(n%d == 0)       // Пока делится (и если делится) на d
        {
            ps.push_back(d);  // вносим в массив
            n /= d;           // и делим на d
        }
    }
    if (n > 1) ps.push_back(n);  // Все что осталось простого - тоже в массив

    if (ps.size() <= 1)   // Если только один нечетный множитель - ответ 2 2 2... 2*d
    {                     // если его нет - просто двойки
        cout << "single\n";
        for(int i = 0; i < two-1; ++i) cout << "2 ";  // Выводим двойки
        cout << (ps.size()==0 ? 2 : 2*ps[0]) << endl; // Последний элемент - 2 или 2d, если есть
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "many\n";
        // Пусть в массиве простых нечетных делителей - d0 d1 d2...
        // Тогда первая выводимая строка - 2 2 .. 2 2*d0 2*d1*d2...

        for(int i = 0; i < two-2; ++i) cout << "2 ";
        cout << 2*ps[0] << " ";        // Это и есть 2*d0
        n = 1;  // Тут будет d1*d2...
        for(int i = 1; i < ps.size(); ++i) n *= ps[i];  // Перемножили
        cout << 2*n << endl;                            // Вывели 2*d1*d2...

        // Второй вывод - 2 2 .. 2 2 2*d0*d1*d2...
        for(int i = 0; i < two-1; ++i) cout << "2 ";    // Вывели двойки
        cout << 2*n*ps[0] << endl;                      // Вывели 2*d0*d1*d2...
    }
}
```

Все это благополучно проходит тестовую систему.. Весь код - https://ideone.com/otGj84

Comment: Как-то много кода, не?

Comment: @Qwertiy Так ведь писалось на коленке со скоростью набора :) - я не пытался сделать красиво или даже эффективно (можно было не разгребать все простые делители - достаточно одного было).

Comment: А, тьфу, я накосячил. Надо на чётные раскладывать, а не на любые.

Comment: @Qwertiy, пожалуйста, помогите реализовать саму функцию. Мне не был понятен Ваш удалённый ответ. Я пытался реализовать хотя бы нахождение `maxPowOf2ThatIsDivederOf(n)`, но не получилось.

Comment: @DaniilSavinov, удалённый ответ был неправильным. Сейчас правильный будет, минутку.

Comment: @DaniilSavinov, исправил.

Comment: @Harry, а какую тестовую систему оно проходит?

Comment: @Qwertiy https://informatics.mccme.ru/mod/statements/view3.php?id=32361&chapterid=112669